# Variable in loop is incorrect

Tags: javascript

Console isn't displaying the correct "people".

My function is as follows:

```
(function() {
  var people, length = 10;
  for (people = 0; people < this.length; people++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(people);
    }, 1000);
  }
})();
```

Comment: What is it displaying? What result do you expect?

Comment: instead of `this.length` shouldn't that be `length`

Comment: Is this `setTimeout("console.log("+people+")", 1000);` what you want? Or you want it to output a number every second?

Comment: Expecting 1 through to 10 to be displayed in console. Can't see it displaying anything but 10. Thanks @raser good pick up.

Comment: Try what I wrote then. And if you want from 1 to 10, the for loop needs to be: `for (people = 1; people <= length; people++) {`

Comment: setTimeout is called from window's context. this inside the function refers to window.

Comment: @Shomz: Sorry i meant 0-9 but thanks!

Comment: I see this question pop up pretty much ever day on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `this.length` is not the local variable `length` in your function.

`this` is just the global object `window`, so `this.length` is just `window.length`.

```
(function() {
    var people,length = 10;
    for (people = 0; people < length; people++) {        
        setTimeout((function(people){ 
           return function() { 
              console.log(people); 
           };
        })(people), 1000);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean like:

```
(function() {
    var people,length = 10;
    for (people = 0; people < length; people++) {
        (function(index) {
            setTimeout(function() { console.log(index); }, 1000);
        })(people);
    }
})();
```

Comment: +1 This is a much nicer way of doing `setTimeout("console.log("+people+")", 1000);`

Comment: +1 and will accept in 7 minutes! :) thanks @Sudhir

Comment: -1 for no explanation. Poster is not going to learn why it is broken.